# LightSensor too much data

Tags: android, sensors, broadcast

I have a LightSensor which broadcasts changes.  Basically it is broadcasting on every sampling even if there is no change from 0.  How should I get the Sensor to only broadcast basically an ON/OFF value.  For example if lux > 0 then light is ON else lux = 0 so light is OFF.

sendLuxUpdate():

```
public class LightSensor extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    public Sensor LightSensor;
    public static Float lightLux;
    TextView tvLightSensorLux;
    public String Lux;

    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d("LightSensor", "OnCreate");
        // Get an instance of the sensor service
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor LightSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        // Test to see if Light Sensor is available
        if (LightSensor != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, LightSensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    public void onStartCommand() {
        Log.d("LightSensor", "OnStartCommand");
    }

    /**
     * protected void onResume() { mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
     * LightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); // super.onResume(); }
     * 
     * protected void onPause() { mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this,
     * LightSensor); // super.onPause(); }
     **/
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        lightLux = event.values[0]; // Final output of this sensor.
        Lux = String.valueOf(lightLux);

        if (lightLux > 0) {
            Log.d("LightSensor", Lux);
            sendLuxUpdate();
        } else {
            float lightLux = 0;
            sendLuxUpdate();
        }

    }

    private void sendLuxUpdate() {
        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message " + Lux);
        Intent intent = new Intent("LuxUpdate");
        intent.putExtra("Lux", Lux);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        stopSelf();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, LightSensor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a flag in your code to determine if it is on or off. Then, before logging anything, check to see if the data is different than the flag. If not, move on. If it is different, make the updates.

Comment: No, that is part of the problem.  The sensor polls constantly.  Basically any value greater than 0 is ON and and value = 0 is OFF.  Question is how to tell it to compare on each value type

Comment: So, you make a boolean lightIsOn or something, and you set it to false initially. If the data is >0 and !lightIsOn -> lightIsOn = true. if the data is 0 and lightIsOn -> lightIsOn = false. Do nothing for any other case. You can't ignore the data otherwise as far as I know. You may be able to limit how often it checks if that is your problem.

Comment: Boolean is not the problem. That is already there. The trick is to get to only report when a light goes form off to on and then only when on to off and not everything in between.

Comment: I think that is an issue with the class you are using. I haven't worked with it before, but you may be able to override it so that it will act how you want. If not, you could try making a new class that will do it for you. I'm guessing that it is something that you won't be able to control, and you will just have to deal with all of the data. Overriding what the class does to create a buffer between the flag and your code seems like the best bet though. That way nothing else will run as a result of the light slightly changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that Sensors send you raw analog data. So they are continuous and data is raw. Or if you are using other sensors too, this method might be called by other sensors. So check type of sensor also.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        lightLux = event.values[0]; // Final output of this sensor.
        Lux = String.valueOf(lightLux);

        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
        final float currentReading = event.values[0];
        if (currentReading > 0){
        //ON
          }
        else
         {//OFF     
           }
        }

    }
```

Also you will see change in value everytime, because it sends too detailed value as it is raw data. You can cast it to `int` if you don't want this.

`int value= (int) event.values[0];`

Hope it helps! Good luck